# Erro: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd

I'm just using "umarshall" - XSD validation:

```
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="50">
          <xs:element name="docZip">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>Informação resumida ou documento fiscal eletrônico de interesse da pessoa ou empresa. O conteúdo desta tag estará compactado no padrão gZip. O tipo do campo é base64Binary.</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any processContents="skip">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Estrutura genérica do documento fiscal eletrônico</xs:documentation>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:any>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="NSU" type="TNSU" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>NSU do documento fiscal</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute name="schema" type="xs:string" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Identificação do Schema XML que será utilizado para validar o XML existente no campo seguinte. Vai identificar o tipo do documento e sua versão. Exemplos: resNFe_v1.00.xsd, procNFe_v3.10.xsd, resEvento_1.00.xsd, procEventoNFe_v1.00.xsd</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:attribute>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
```

I have this exception:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'docZip' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.]
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you are trying to unmarshal the `service response or request xml` which is using the above `xsd`, that xml has a `'docZip'` element with some text in it other with it's child elements. As shown below.

```
<docZip>
    Text which is not allowed
    <childElement>
    </chilElement>
</docip>
```

That's why the xsd validation is failing. So capture the actual xml and see if you don't have direct text inside docZip element

For more detail on this error, refer [this](https://wiki.xmldation.com/Support/Validator/cvc-complex-type-2-3) link